# Rightfax Integration with JAVA API

Tags: rightfax

I am trying to do some POC on Rightfax integration with JAVA API. Installed all required components in Rightfax Server (JAVA/XML API) and configured the IIS (took care while installing the rightfax server) 
    while running the sample java program getting following message

```
Msg: Failed to load XML into DOM tree.
```

Could someone help me if there is any configuration is missing in Rightfax server side or at IIS

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create a outbound fax object
RFaxSubmit faxSubmit= new RFaxSubmit();
//set XMLNS and make sure you have XML_FAX_SUBMIT_schema.xml in your classpath.
faxSubmit.m_FaxDocument.setXMLNS("classpath:XML_FAX_SUBMIT_schema.xml");
```

This file must be available on your RightFax server, @ this location \RightFax\Production\xml\schemas\XML_FAX_SUBMIT_schema.xml
download this file or ask server support and add it in your classpath.